# Inverted Corner Radius on all four corners of a UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a UIView that has a reversed/inverted corner radius on all four corners like this:

[image: inverted rounded corners].

I've tried looking for solutions here but could not find what I needed. I would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Looks more like a path shape of some kind - could also be multi-part back ground image

Comment: Yes, the design looks like it has a layer but I need a way to achieve this. I can not use an image as a background because I need to increase and decrease the UIView itself and the image would stretch out and I don't want that.

Comment: You can use an image, just make it stretchable as outlined in the “Defining a Stretchable Image” in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage). That way, it stretches in the middle, not the edges where you have your rounded corners. That having been said, a `CAShapeLayer` with an appropriate `cgPath` of a `UIBezierPath` works great, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `UIView` subclass that defines its backing layer to be a `CAShapeLayer`, configure that shape layer, and then respond to `layoutSubviews`, updating the path associated with that shape layer in such a way that it updates dynamically as the size of the view changes (e.g. maybe you have constraints that change the size based upon the dimensions of the device in question):

```
@IBDesignable
class InvertedCornerView: UIView {
    // define backing layer and provide computed property to make it easier to interact with

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }
    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer    { return layer as! CAShapeLayer }

    // a few public properties that dictate what it looks like
    // these are inspectable in case you want to show/customize this right in IB

    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5        { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20    { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = .black { didSet { shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor } }
    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .clear   { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor } }

    // basic lifecycle methods

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private utility methods

private extension InvertedCornerView {
    func configure() {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
    }

    func updatePath() {
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.minY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .pi,         endAngle: .pi / 2,     clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .pi * 3 / 2, endAngle: .pi,         clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0,           endAngle: .pi * 3 / 2, clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .pi / 2,     endAngle: 0,           clockwise: false)
        path.close()

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

There are lots of variations on the theme (it looks good with cubic beziers for the corners, too), but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea. The heart of the idea is to use a `CAShapeLayer` whose path is updated by `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the code. I'll try the code now and will update you here.

Comment: Wow!! This works as intended. Thank you so much. I'm going to understand every single line you've written and hope to grow more as a developer.